# Program not producing correct output, however code is reviewed

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, char

I am writing a C program that keeps track of the total cost of items in a shopping cart.

Input must be taken in `float` for the price and then for each input, another input to ask to continue is to be taken.

As of now, the program does not output anything, which makes me feel like it is struck in some kind of a non-terminating loop or something.

I have written the code, but when I compile it, it does not produce the correct output. I have been trying to resolve this problem in such a simple program for half an hour, and still not able to identify the error.

Is something wrong in the code, or is the compiler messing with me?

Note: I have checked this with a few online compilers as well, and yet the same output.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float price, total;
    char choice;

    total = 0;

    choice = 'y';
    while (1) {
        if (choice == 'n') {
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter price: ");
        scanf("%f", &price);
        total += price;
        printf("Continue?: ");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
    }

    printf("%.2f", total);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer) may be an issue after the edit. Use `scanf(" %c", &choice);` instead. You might also try `fflush(stdout);` when printing data without a newline at the end.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &choice);` ==> `scanf(" %c", &choice);` Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). And always **always** check the function value returned by `scanf` (the number of items successfully scanned).

Comment: Aside: `while (choice != 'n')` would be simpler.

Comment: @WeatherVane actually that's what I had originally written. But I thought maybe the error was due to that and changed it to that :).